# Resampling high resolution binary raster

Tags: r, resolution, resampling, aggregation

I have a large, high resolution raster of binary data that I need to reproject and resample to align with a lower resolution dataset. Because the original data is binary, I need to aggregate using the mean function to find the percentage of the aggregated grid cells that have the value. I have a basic workflow, but am wondering if I can better preserve the original data by changing the order of operations. Currently, I'm reprojecting the data, then aggregating, then resampling.

Is there an order or method that would better preserve the original data?

Here is my current workflow, with a reproducible example:

Step 1: Reproject raster 1 to lat/lon to align with raster 2. Raster 1 was originally 500m sinusoidal; it ends up with a resolution of 0.0045 in lat/lon. Raster 2 has a resolution of 0.25. Reproducible example approximating the two rasters:

```
library(raster)

r1 <- raster(xmn=-9.872, xmx=-7.856, ymn=-6.57262, ymx=-4.55662, ncols=448, nrows=448)
nr1=ncell(r1)
d1 <- rbinom(n=nr1/4, size=1, prob=0.05) #multiple distributions to make things more visually interesting
d2 <- rbinom(n=nr1/4, size=1, prob=0.4)
d3 <- rbinom(n=nr1/4, size=1, prob=0.1)
d4 <- rbinom(n=nr1/4, size=1, prob=0.3)
d <- c(d1,d2, d3, d4)
r1 <- setValues(r1, d)

plot(r1)

r2 <- raster(xmn=-9.875, xmx=-7.875, ymn=-7.125, ymx=-2.625, ncols=8, nrows=10)
```

[image: r1 plot]
Step 2: Aggregate raster 1 to the approximate resolution of raster 2, using the mean function to calculate the percentage of the aggregated cells that are 1s. Since raster 1 has a resolution of 0.0045 and raster 2 has a resolution of 0.25, and 0.25/0.0045 = 55.55556, I'll use 56 as the aggregation factor.

```
#aggregate
r1_agg <- aggregate(r1, 56, fun=mean)

#extend to the extent of r2, which is bigger
r1_ext <- extend(r1_agg, r2)
plot(r1_ext)
```

[image: aggregated r1]
Step 3: Resample raster 1 to the grid of raster 2.

```
r1_resam <- resample(r1_ext, r2,method='bilinear')
plot(r1_resam)
```

[image: r1 resampled]
Obviously the last step makes significant changes to the structure of the data. I know that to some degree this is inevitable, but I'm wondering if there are any steps I should be doing at different times and/or differently in order to preserve the original data as closely as possible.